# Duplicate last table row but change class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following question.

I have a table, like the example below. The plan is to copy a row but not with a new class. The class should change in a remove class. Example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klaas3/wgRYR/ The goal is to keep the last row always green and the others red.

```
<table class="test">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>header 1</td>
        <td>header 2</td>
        <td>header 3</td>
        <td>header 4</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="1">
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td class="remove"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2">
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td class="remove"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new">
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td class="new"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I use the last column(with the new and remove class or red and green colors) as a button.

I have the following allready, but something seems to go wrong:

```
$("table.test tr.new:last td.new").click(function(){
$('table.test tr.new:last  td.new').removeClass('new').addClass('remove').fadeIn("fast");
$('table.test tr.new:last').clone(true).insertAfter('table.test tr.new:last');
});
```

Mind you, I am not a very experienced jquery user. Also when the cell class is changed I will change the table row class as well with a db id. (But that I will try myself with a working sample).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You have no td.add class.  You have td.new.  Can you post sample code on jsfiddle?

Comment: You are selecting a tr with a class of add, but you don't have any rows with that class in your example.

Comment: as requested a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/klaas3/wgRYR/

the goal is to have 1 green cell at the bottom and the others red. in the example they all turn red.

Comment: I know you tagged this question with JavaScript, but why don't you use CSS3 selectors? `table tbody tr td:last-child{
    background-color: red;
}
table tbody tr:last-child td:last-child{
    background-color: green;
}` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgRYR/1/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You need to clone the element before changing the classes

Also to turn off/remove the click event handler use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("table.test tr.new:last td.new").click(function(){
    var x = $('table.test tr.new:last').clone(true);
    // you can use "this" instead of $('table.test tr.new:last  td.new') since you are inside it's event handler
    $(this).removeClass('new').addClass('remove').off('click');// <-- removes handler from current td 
    x.insertAfter('table.test tr.new:last');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XvDBC/

Comment: Allmost what i mean! except when i click one of the added rows with red cells they still produce new records. It should be only when i press the green "button".

Comment: this has cost me a lot of time thnx!