# Jquery duplicate table row and changing events onclick

Tags: jquery, html

Yesterday i questioned how to add a new table row but change the css of the duplicated row. I got an answer to that question!([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635581/duplicate-last-table-row-but-change-class-in-jquery)) however a new issue has arised.

i have a table as follow:

```
<table class="test">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td><b>header 1</b></td>
    <td><b>header 2</b></td>
    <td><b>header 3</b></td>
    <td><b>header 4</b></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="1">
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td class="remove"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="2">
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td class="remove"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="new">
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td class="new"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>​
```

Jquery code:

```
$("table.test tr.new:last td.new").click(function(){
     var x = $('table.test tr.new:last').clone(true);
     $(this).removeClass('new').addClass('remove').off('click');    
     x.insertAfter('table.test tr.new:last');
});
     $("table.test tr td.remove").click(function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

When i click the td.new cell i want to add a row. This is working. Also the class is changed in a td.remove cell. However the click events do not work correct. The remove cell should allways remove a row. I have figured out that I have to use .off() and .on functions but I can't seem to understand the logic behind this functions. The following image is what i am aiming for: [postimage](http://postimage.org/image/3ro51n5rv/af063a4c/)

Jsfiddle example of what i have now can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/klaas3/wgRYR/2/)

Comment: need to fix your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to adding the row Dynamically right.. So you need to **delegate the event..**

Instead of

```
$("table.test tr td.remove").click(function(){
```

try

```
$("table.test").on('click','td.remove', function(){
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wgRYR/5/)**

**UPDATE**

You can handle both the case in a single handler itself..
Made a few modifications in your code..

```
$("table.test").on('click', 'td.remove,td.new', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('new')) {
        var x = $('table.test tr.new').clone();
        $this.removeClass('new').addClass('remove');
        $this.closest('tr').removeClass('new');
        x.insertAfter('table.test tr:last');
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('remove')) {
        $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery .live(), I know it's going to be deprecated, but it would be a simple starting point for you. 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

It will hook on the remove elements that will be added to the DOM in the future. SO you would not need to handle any reinitilizations and stuff.

EDIT:

So back again to .live(), since it is deprecated you should achieve that by:

$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);

In your case:
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
//whatever it is you want to do
});

Comment: .live() was deprcated a long time back.. I mean from version 1.7 .. jQuery is currently at 1.8.2

Comment: true that, but as this looks like a very simple begginer question, I think I would mention it as it is easier to use. I will update the answer